# Openstack allow api access from vm

Tags: openstack, openstack-neutron, openstack-api

We are currently using Openstack newtown. We can access the API using client on public endpoint from any computer, but the vm don't have access to it, they can ping the IP and dns name but can't curl or access using openstack-client. How can we allow connection from VM to API ?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your public API endpoint is externally accessible, the network on which your virtual machine resides will need external access.  This can be achieved in a few different ways, depending on your current configuration.  You can create a Neutron provider network/subnet which will provide access to a physical network and gateway to the outside world. You can then boot your instance directly on the provider network.  More information on Neutron provider networks can be found at [docs.openstack.org](http://docs.openstack.org/user-guide/cli-create-and-manage-networks.html).

Comment: Public endpoints is available, and vm has floating IP associate to it, I can ping the API fqdn enpoint from the vm but I have a timeout when curl or using Openstack client. Doesn't happend from a controller, or other device. Vm can curl or ping any other adresses without problems.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that floating IP don't give the route of my external network.
I add route using neutron and now all is working perfectly. for info the command is:

```
neutron router-update demo-routeur  --routes type=dict list=true destination=192.168.0.27/27,nexthop=10.0.0.1
```